# linq to entity framework: something like isnull

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have:

```
a = b.Sum(...) + c.Sum(...)
```

where `b,c` are entities.
The problem is: when at least one of (`b.Sum(...)`, `c.Sum(...)`) is null then `a` will be null. I'd like null be treated as 0. How would I do this?

Comment: I think `a` is a scalar, not an entity. And what if 1 of the sums is `null` and the other returns a number?

Comment: right, fixed. When at least one is null a is null too.

Comment: But what do you want a to be when it's  '12 + null' ?  0 or 12 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in LINQ2SQL you can cast to `int?` manually and then handle the null case

```
a = ((int?)b.Sum(...) + c.Sum(...)).GetValueOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this

```
a = ( b.Sum(...) + c.Sum(...)) ?? 0;
```

now if the expression is null, a will be 0;

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use null coelesce for this:

```
a = (b.Sum(..) + c.Sum(...)) ?? 0;
```

NOTE: unchecked syntax! not sure what your sums are doing!

Have a look at the following MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx